# tornado: How to create file-like object that writes to a RequestHandler?

Tags: python, tornado

In my application, I'm trying to create a handler that streams large files out to the client. These files are created by another module (`tarfile` to be exact).

What I want is a file-like object that instead of writing to a socket or an actual file on the disk, proxies to the `RequestHandler.write` method.

Here's what my current naive implementation looks like:

```
import tornado.gen
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class HandlerFileObject(object):
    def __init__(self, handler):
        self.handler = handler

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def write(self, data):
        self.handler.write(data)
        yield self.handler.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.handler.finish()


class DownloadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.set_status(200)
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
        fp = HandlerFileObject(self)
        with open('/dev/zero', 'rb') as devzero:
            for _ in range(100*1024):
                fp.write(devzero.read(1024))
        fp.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", DownloadHandler)
    ])
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

It works, but the problem is that all of the data is loaded into RAM and is not released until I stop the application.
What would be a better/more idiomatic/resourceful way of going about this?

Answer (score 3):

`get()` also needs to be a coroutine and yield when calling `fp.write()`.  By making write a coroutine you've made your object less file-like - most callers will simply ignore its return value, masking exceptions and interfering with flow control.  The file-like interface is synchronous so you'll probably need to do these operations in other threads so you can block them as needed.